# Displaying HTML Element Count

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm doing Free Code Camp projects with User Stories requiring a minimum number of different elements.

I came up with the idea of using some of the page to display an element count and thought it would be simple to implement. Famous last words I know.

Spent a few hours reviewing MDN , W3, W3Schools, ... examples and documentation. Also searched here.

I've tried using botj javascript and jQuery and can get results in javascript but they are incorrect. The jQuery stuff doesn't work at all.

```
<head>
        <script src= 
            "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"> 
        </script>

        <script src=
        "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
        </script>
  
</head>

<body>

<!-- much deletia -->

        <div class="ToC">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">HTML Element Use</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td><td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td><td><script>document.write(HTMLCollection.length)</script></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>p</td><td><script>document.write(document.getElementsByTagName('p').length);</script></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>div</td><td><script>document.write($( div ).length;)</script></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- even more deletia -->

</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem #1 - `document.write`

Comment: Problem number two: 2 jQuery versions.

Comment: hey, really sorry.  Iedited your question to make it a snippet (good) but I thought I was working on a copy and made changes (bad).  anyway, if you run the snippet now it should work

Comment: @DCR — I rolled back your edit of the question so the OP's problems are still apparent.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.

I commented out the first javascript version and am using the latest one. The rest of the scripting (dynamically displaying window width & height) still works.

Can you say more about what is wrong with document.write?


I'm guessing there is a reason to create a variable.

I don't see why I can't just write out built-in dynamically updated property values.

Comment: document.write only works while the page is loading; If you call it after the page is done loading, it will overwrite the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var divCnt = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length
var pCnt = document.getElementsByTagName('p').length
var tCnt = document.getElementsByTagName('*').length

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = tCnt;

document.getElementById('div').textContent = divCnt;
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = pCnt;
```

```html
<head>
        <script src= 
            "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"> 
        </script>

        <script src=
        "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
        </script>
  
</head>

<body>

<!-- much deletia -->

        <div class="ToC">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">HTML Element Use</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td><td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td><td id='total'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>p</td><td id='p'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>div</td><td id='div'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- even more deletia -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets all of the elements from a simple `document.querySelectorAll('*')` which matches everything. Calling that returns a NodeList, so you want to [turn that into an array](https://gomakethings.com/converting-a-nodelist-to-an-array-with-vanilla-javascript/) using `Array.from(...)`.

The next line uses the [Array `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to turn that array of many elements into a single map.
It does that by using the node `tagName` as the key into the map, and assigning the node to that key. Actually it has to create an array on the map element first, so it can push all of the similar nodes onto that array.
That is done by using the element type name, such as `DIV`, as the key into the map. If that's the first time a node type has been seen it creates the array and then, in all cases, pushes the Element into the array.

```js
let allelements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'));

let result = allelements.reduce(function(map, obj) {
  if (map[obj.tagName] == null) {
    map[obj.tagName] = [];
  }
  map[obj.tagName].push(obj);
  return map;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="div-one">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
</div>
<div id="div-two">
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
</div>
```

You can then iterate the map keys to find how many of each element type there is.
If all you care about is the total element count you can skip reducing the array and just use `allelements.length` which tells you how many total nodes were selected.

---

Notice this gets ***ALL*** elements! You can limit it to just the `<body>` elements by first selecting the body and then using querySelectorAll on *that*.

In this example I've also added summarizing the number of each element type to the console.

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');

let allelements = Array.from(body.querySelectorAll('*'));

let result = allelements.reduce(function(map, obj) {
  if (map[obj.tagName] == null) {
    map[obj.tagName] = [];
  }
  map[obj.tagName].push(obj);
  return map;
}, {});

console.log('Resulting map =', result);

console.log('Counts:');
for (tag of Object.keys(result)) {
 console.log(tag.toLowerCase(), result[tag].length);
}
```

```html
<div id="div-one">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
</div>
<div id="div-two">
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
</div>
```